# Checking environment variables' value in Makefile

Tags: shell, make

I have a Makefile target, in which I have to check the value of an environment variable. But, I don't get the exact syntax of it. Tried hard, but can't find it. Any help is appreciated.

Environment variable name: TEST, its value: "TRUE"

```
test_target: 
    ifeq ($(TEST),"TRUE")
            echo "Do something"
    endif
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"TRUE","TRUE"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq ("TRUE","TRUE")'
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `ifeq()` directive has to be in column 1, remove any leading whitespace ie

```
test_target: 
ifeq ($(TEST),"TRUE")
        echo "Do something"
endif
```

^ no whitespace

Comment: when i do this I get "missing seperator" because of missing intendation

Answer (score 31):

You must not put `ifeq` after TAB.  Spaces are allowed.  Read [GNU Make document](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html).

```
test_target: 
ifeq ($(TEST),"TRUE")
    echo "Do something"
endif
```

Also note that it compares `$(TEST)` with `"TRUE"` as is:

```
$ make TEST=TRUE
make: Nothing to be done for 'test_target'.

$ make TEST='"TRUE"'
echo "Do something"
Do something
```

Comment: This bit was extra helpful - Also note that it compares $(TEST) with "TRUE" as is:. Thanks